# Is there a way to deploy into a vagrant VM using Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, vagrant

I'd like to setup a vagrant instance outside of my project directory.  Is there a way to deploy rails into the vagrant VM with capistrano as I would to my real production host?

I'm trying to use server as "localhost" but I get:

```
connection failed for: localhost (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out.  In case others care to know:

1. I created a separate folder and did the whole Vagrant init there.
2. I configured the Vagrant file to use a bridged network.
3. I signed into my vagrant VM (`$ vagrant ssh`) and ran `ifconfig` to get my IP address.
4. I added that IP address to my Capistrano deploy file.
5. I passed along vagrants ssh info to my local configs: `vagrant ssh-config >> ~/.ssh/config`
6. I ran my deploy, when prompted for the SSH password, I used `vagrant`

It worked.

Comment: You could also use hostonly networking. Two advantages. One, can assign ip address, so don't need to look it up everytime. Two, machines don't have access to the network at large. Otherwise instructions would be same.

Answer (score 19):

You can also feed Vagrant's SSH options to Capistrano (most of the `:ssh_options` go directly to Net::SSH, http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v1/chapter-2.html, see "Options") so there is no need to mess your real ~/.ssh/config

```
set :user, 'vagrant'
set :ssh_options, {port: 2222, keys: ['~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key']}

role :web, "localhost" 
...
```

(Of course, you shouldn't really be using the `insecure_private_key` or the default root/vagrant passwords unless properly firewalled, but the principle remains the same.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and thanks to the solution of @Nathan I could fix the issue. I have a different release setup. Was trying to test release a ruby project in my VM with Capistrano, but had a authentication error on user@localhost. SSH user@localhost worked fine.

My build setup is Oracle Virtual Box with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed as VM. To connect with SSH to your VM with Capistrano you have to do the following:

1. Go to your settings of the VM e.g. ubuntu 22.04 LTS;
2. Go to Network and set Attached to `Bridged Adapter`
3. Set Name to your local network: mine was `wlp4s0`
4. Set Promisecuous Mode to `Allow All`;
5. Now restart your Ubuntu VM and check your ip under `inet` by running `ifconfig`;
6. Try to connect to your server with SSH to check if it still works `ssh user_for_cap@ip_address`
7. Put that ip as config in your cap file and connect with ssh_options like: `server 'ip_address', user: 'user_for_cap', roles: %w[app], port: 22`

It Worked!